# Should I use a private variable or property

Tags: vb.net, variables, properties

I am working in vb.net and have a couple of variables in a class. While looking over my code I am trying to decide if I have declared my variables appropriately. I have two dates, two strings, a list, and a thread. I have the first four declared as private properties and the last two as just variables. What is the best practice for deciding which one use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of having something as a property, as opposed to a field, is that you can customize when happens when the value is read or set (the getter and setter methods).  If the value is public, it's typically best to always make it a property, since you may need to customize the behavior at some point in the future, and to change a public field to a public property will break compatibility with already compiled code.  However, if the value is private, then that is not even a concern.  Therefore, for simplicity sake, I would say that all private values should be stored as fields, unless you need to customize its behavior with property getter/setter methods.

Comment: Auto properties blur that line a little bit. ;-)

Comment: @EdDeGagne How so?  Auto-properties still function the same way.  They are just short-hand for the programmer.

Comment: Because most developers that have to ask the question that was asked, don't know or understand the difference.

Comment: @EdDeGagne Sounds like something a bitter Massachusetts socialist would say :)

Comment: Touche Steven. :)  But not a socialist, I think I am the only Republican left in this state.

Comment: You are now that I left :)  You say you aren't one, but if you still live there, you can't be that adverse to it :)  Come on, man!  NH is a stone's throw away...

Comment: ok, that makes since but it raises a slight side question: Assuming I am working with a private variable: whats the difference in using "private test as string" vs "Dim test as String"?

Comment: Lol, don't think we haven't considered it my friend. I do all my firearm shopping in your state, that good enough for now?  ;-)

Comment: In that context, `Dim` means exactly the same thing as `Public`.  So, by using `Dim`, it's not really as private as you might be thinking it is :)  I would never recommend using `Dim` for class fields.  Always use `Public`, `Private`, `Protected`, or `Friend`.  They are more clear and specific.

Comment: `Private test as string` is basically just an abbreviation for `Private Dim test as String`

Comment: @EdDeGagne Fair enough :)  Good luck to you as they drag you down kicking an screaming.

Comment: Agree with Steven completely, I'll add that you should really limit the use of Dim for variable declaration to declaring variables within a method or procedure.

Comment: Try to think of `Dim` as the terribly embarrassing throw-back to BASIC syntax that it is, and keep it hidden in your methods as discreetly as possible so that you can stand tall as a "real" programmer next to your C# counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the difference in this MSDN Article.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk5e8eth.aspx

Basically if you only want to store a local value without anything else in your class you use a variable. Properties offer more advanced features. You can execute code to your liking if you assign a value to a property or retrieve it (if you define Get/Set methods for the property, again see the MSDN articles).
If the value is public I would suggest a property since you can more tightly control what it is set to by using for example over/underflow checks in the Set method.